# Space Complexity Reduction for Dynamic Time Warping

Tags: dynamic-time-warping

I'm currently trying to use dynamic time warping to group a large number of time-series I have. Unfortunately, each series has around 400000 entries, and Python can't handle creating a 400000 x 400000 matrix. Is there a another way to use DTW that doesn't use as much space?

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the distance (not the warping path) then DTW is just O(n) not O(n^2). Does that solve your problem?
Useful tutorial [https://www.cs.unm.edu/~mueen/DTW.pdf](https://www.cs.unm.edu/%7Emueen/DTW.pdf)